# Passing Ref from Parent component in Child using Ref in React

Tags: reactjs, ref

I have a parent component and a child component.
When I click on Button in the parent component (Box) - the child component (ContainedModal) is opening.

Issue: When Child component is opened - it should change the css (height and overflow) of parent component.

What I need:
I need to move this logic into child component with using Ref. So I need to assign Ref to Parent () and get this Ref in child component.
[My parent component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80SZj.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by putting the ref on the div you want in the ContainerModal component like this:

```
    const ContaineModal = ({modalRef}) => {
    return <div ref={modalRef}>

    </div>
}

<ContaineModal modalRef={reference}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you should take a look at Forwarding Ref
https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html
this is a way you can initiate a tag it the parents and pass to the child.
a code example can be seen in the doc